# PRIME NUMBER(the if function and being divided by 2)

Tags: java

Hi I'm having a little problem about prime function.

```
public static boolean isPrime(long num) {

    for (long i=3; i <num/2; i++) {
        if (num % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I don't understand why it has to be num/2 and the if(num % i == 0). 
so does it mean that if 
num = 10 and i = 4 which would result to 2. makes 4 a prime number?

sorry if it's a stupid question, I just started coding \m/

edit: also, can someone explain the  `if(num % 1 ==0)`

Comment: " why it has to be num/2" It doesn't. In fact, this checks more numbers than you need to.

Comment: This method is wrong, because it says that 4, 6, 8 and 10 (and lots of others) are prime numbers. So if you're asking why it's written this way, it shouldn't be.

Comment: "makes 4 a prime numeber?" It would, because you don't check 2.

Comment: what should be the code? I'm getting frustrated about it. 

thanks for the replies!

Answer (score 1):

if you want to write a code to check whether is it is prime number or not then you need to change loop initialization.

long i=3  --> long i=2. Because prime number should not be divisible by any number other than 1. So you should start divide the number by 2,

Comment: Even if that was corrected, it would still say 4 is prime, because of the `i <num/2` condition.

Comment: what if     i<num would that fix it?

Comment: @Light `i <= num/2` would be sufficient

Comment: forgot to that condition @khelwood